# is it valid statement?

Tags: ios4

```
SqlAssignementAppDelegate *appDelegate =(SqlAssignementAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
lblresNam.text =[appDelegate.Record objectAtIndex:0];
```

lblresNam is UITextField type object
Record is NSMutableArray

but my application is terminating..
Please give me solutions...

Comment: What error you get in console when app terminates? These 2 lines of code look ok it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Record object a property, so you know it's being retained, and so dot notation will be available?

More likely the culprit, did you forget to @synthesize Record so it has a getter?

If you neglected to do either one of those, **appDelegate.Record** is an error.